# Compute needed to use Azure blob storage?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I have an ASP.NET application running on shared hosting and want to use Windows Azure blob storage to store images (my shared hosting has limited storage).  My application will upload and download these images from/to the client PC.

I created a new cloud project to test this out and got it working successfully with the offline storage emulator, but I noticed that the cloud project has a web worker role which, I believe, needs a compute instance when deployed to Azure.  Azure storage is very cheap, but if I need a compute instance for my application to talk to to access it then it becomes much more expensive, even with the smallest instance.

My question is - do I need a compute instance in order to upload and download files to blob storage or can my application talk directly to the blob storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You do not need compute instances to talk to Azure storage.  You can talk to Azure storage directly from client apps or from apps hosted by other providers.

Nor do you need to create a new Cloud project within Visual Studio to take advantage of Azure blob storage.  Simply, reference appropriate .DLLs (Azure Storage Client) and you're good to go.

Comment: Example client app I used to setup my blob storage container is CloudXplorer - http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer (Free Download)

Comment: Thanks Igorek.  Every example I'd found worked through creating a full Azure web application, but I was able to reference the .DLLs, add a web.config item referencing development storage as the storage provider and get it working without having to create a web application or a compute instance.

Comment: Glad you found my answer useful.  Why did you un-accept the answer? It was marked as Accepted before